# Ordering a dictionary by a given key value

Tags: python, csv

I'm studying about how to work with csv files with Python (which I'm new to) and downloaded [the following table](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/oscar_age_female.csv), it has 89 entries with various oscar given to female actresses. I'm having problems wrapping my head around looping over key/values in dictionaries when I want specific sorting...in this case, sorting the actresses by their age.

I've tried a few solutions searching around here but couldn't understand or apply it to my code (which is very simple at the moment). What I know is that I have OrderedDict objects with a dictionary inside and it has a tuple for each key, value, e.g:

```
[OrderedDict([('Index', '1'), ('Year', '1928'), ('Age', '22'), ('Name', 'Janet Gaynor'), ('Movie', 'Seventh Heaven, Street Angel and Sunrise: A Song of Two Humans')]).
```

Current code just prints everything to console:

```
import csv

results = []

with open('oscar_age_female.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.DictReader(File)
    for row in reader:
        results.append(row)
    print(results)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read the csv correctly you need to add in [skipinitialspace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) otherwise the movies which contain commas in their name were being parsed out incorrectly.

```
import csv

results = []

with open('oscar_age_female.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.DictReader(File, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        results.append(row)
```

In order to sort the list of dictionaries by a key is then trivial once the above step is added:

```
print(sorted(results, key=lambda k: k['Age']))  # Youngest to oldest
print(sorted(results, key=lambda k: k['Age'], reverse=True))  # Oldest to youngest
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary) is a good post on sorting lists of dicts by their keys

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, I still don't know how to use those lambdas, which might explain why I was having trouble.